# Error saving using SharedPreferences

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I am saving a few variables using sharedpreferences but my save method crashes the app with a null pointer exception.

```
public void save() {

    SharedPreferences sp = context.getSharedPreferences(saveFile, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    //Use the editor for easier management, no calling edit and commit so many times. 
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();

    editor.putInt("X", player.getX());
    editor.putInt("Y", player.getY());
    editor.putInt("level", player.getLevel());
    editor.putFloat("xp", player.getXp());
    editor.commit();
}
```

getSharedPreferences() does not work by itself and needs to have context. before it, which could be a problem. I have context defined, SharedPreferences imported, so why does this not work?

**EDIT: Here is the logcat**

```
02-18 20:21:49.958: E/AndroidRuntime(1005): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-89
02-18 20:21:49.958: E/AndroidRuntime(1005): java.lang.NullPointerException
02-18 20:21:49.958: E/AndroidRuntime(1005): at com.package.game.GameScreen.save(GameScreen.java:856)
02-18 20:21:49.958: E/AndroidRuntime(1005): at com.package.game.GameScreen.updateLevelUp(GameScreen.java:364)
```

The save method is above and the line:

```
SharedPreferences sp = context.getSharedPreferences(saveFile, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

is line 856. updateLevelUp is the method that is called when the player levels up and when that screen is exited the game resumes and save() is called.

Comment: Post the stacktrace. Which line is null?

Comment: Consider saving a reference to `safeFile.edit()` and calling `commit()` once.

Comment: "loadSave" logically seems to be null

Comment: @EvZ Could be `context`, `players`, maybe even one of the returned values.

Comment: @Sam true , was a quick answer.

Comment: The second line is null, and loadSave is define as "public static final String loadSave = "gameSave";"

Answer (score 1):

Your `context` variable is `null`. Make sure that it has been initialized, and that you aren't calling this code before the `onCreate()` of the respective `Context`.

Comment: Sorry, but what do I set it to?

Comment: @user2005938 Set it to either your Activity or Application context. Or even better, use `getApplicationContext()` directly in its place

Comment: How do I set it to Application context? getApplicationContext() doesn't work for me.

Comment: You would set it using `context = getApplicationContext()` anyways. What do you mean by it doesn't work for you? Where are you calling this code?

Comment: When I do Context context = getApplicationContext(); it says the method getApplicationContext is undefined.

Comment: In which class is this code? Is it an activity or a service or a broadcast receiver?

Answer (score 0):

As a good rule, you want to utilize a `SharedPreferences.Editor` when managing SharedPreferences.

Here's a simpler way:

```
public void save() {
    SharedPreferences saveFile = context.getSharedPreferences(loadSave, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    //Use the editor for easier management, no calling edit and commit so many times. 
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = saveFile.edit();

    editor.putInt("x", player.get());
    editor.putInt("Y", player.getY());
    editor.putInt("level", player.getLevel());
    editor.putFloat("xp", player.getXp());

    //Save changes now
    editor.commit();
}
```

Also, in case you still get a nullpointer after this implementation, make sure you post the log so we can track down the exception.

Comment: This is a good tip, but I don't think it should change anything.

Comment: First, he did not post the log, meaning we don't even know for sure what the problem is. At first sight, the only thing I find to be problematic is the calling of edit() and commit () several times, mostly the commit() call would be a common cause for issues.